# ALTER TABLE Database NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_XXXXXX_DB

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I need to make an update on a table (sql 2008 server).

I use sqlcmd and my update is on a file named update.sql and i use sqlcmd for run it.

In this update, i need to replace a value for an other.

Example:

```
use db
go

update db SET fab=9 where fab=10
Go
update db set fab=7 where fab=8
GO
update db set fab=6 where fab=17
GO
update db set fab=11 where fab=12
GO
```

And I have this message :

Message 2627, Level 14, State 1 sqlserveur Server, Line 1 Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint PK_database can not insert duplicate key in object dbo.database. duplicate key value is <2.9 the statement has been terminated

Could you please tell me how I can use THE NOCHEK CONTRAINT, because I've try it but it's does work.

thank you very Much!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE Test_Table 
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT your_Constraint_Name
GO
```

This is one way of disabling your constraints but it only works for `Foreign keys` and `check constraints`.

Your Error Message says `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint` this cant be disabled you will need to drop the Primary Key.

Comment: Is there a way for NOCHECK the primary key?